# Import tensorflow_hub in PyCharm

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow-hub

I cannot import tensorflow_hub in PyCharm. I'm using Pycharm 2020.1.1

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

I tried in PyCharm console and in cmd:

```
pip install tensorflow-hub
```

But PyCharm still does not see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it by method:

```
File => Settings... => Project => Python Interpreter => Add button => Search "tensorflow-hub" => Install Pakage
```

Use `tensorflow-hub` instead `tensorflow_hub`. They are the same.

It work for me!

[image]

[image]